# Height of div not extending to 100%

Tags: html, css

Here is the final result of what my page is(not much fancy stuff yet): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bWa7B/embedded/result/) - [bWa7B](http://jsfiddle.net/bWa7B/embedded/result/). I am trying for the `div#remaining` to occupy the rest of the page(with white color, and put the footer at its bottom.

I know this little hack can be performed using a pretty easy [`jQuery`](http://abcoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/three-column-layout-js-equal-height.html); like the one used [here](http://abcoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/three-column-layout-js-equal-height.html). But I want to keep my styling to CSS majorly(for many users disable their cookies and JavaScript in browsers while visiting.

I have tried nearly all possible combinations of `overflow: hidden;`, `display: table-cell;` and others from as many links as I could traverse in the last 15 hours or so. But, after **many failed** attempts at achieving my target; I just have to ask.

Some of my *better* results are linked here:

1. [bWa7B/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/bWa7B/1/)
2. [bWa7B/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/bWa7B/2/)
3. [bWa7B/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/bWa7B/3/)
4. [bWa7B/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/bWa7B/4/)

## End Result

I want my end result to have the white-background-colored `div#remaining` to occupy the entire page, with inheriting the margin and width of the body tag. Also, the `div#right` must be covering the entire height of parent **`div`**, i.e. `#remaining`.

## PS

By better results, I mean where at least a change was observed, contrary to my other edits, which did not affect my results much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use a wrapper instead of fiddling with positions.

You make a wrapper around all of those divs. so on top of the title div you put

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
<here the rest of your divs>
</div>
```

and in the css you make it like this:

```
#wrapper{
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:#fff;
}
```

This gives everything a white background including your footer though. however, if you then give your footer the same color background as it has now you wouldn't even notice. You can also close the wrapper before the footer gets in it.

Comment: Isn't my `#remaining` acting as a wrapper itself?

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean. Your website is honestly confusing me. Probably because of the preset stuff I've not seen before yet.
If you put the wrapper around your header,(if you want footer too) and content only, it should give you a background from the red top all the way to your footer. this should leave the dark background intact on the sides.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/bWa7B/6/show/light/) fiddle shows how it takes up the entire body. How long you want the body to be is up to you.

Comment: It is a good solution, but it can be achieved by just editing the `body` tag directly, which I am not inclined to use, as it will be a PHP generated document, with different data being loaded in different `div`s. But, thanks, it can be used as a final result if all else fails.

Comment: Yeah, I have to wait 14 more days, until I'm able to change it. :(

Comment: I meant that, the result from your fiddle can be achieved by just editing the body tag itself.

Comment: correct, but how does that make it an unviable solution? you **can** modify the body tag, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
 left: 0;
```

for div#remaining will fix your problem.

Comment: That makes the `div#remaining` to disinherit the body tag's width and margin. [Check](http://jsfiddle.net/bWa7B/7/embedded/result/)

Comment: @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS then check Asad answer. I misunderstood your problem